# What is "dummy_func" in Python

Tags: python

I am seeing the below segment in the application's source code. I am wondering what is the purpose of `dummy_func` in Python programming.

It's in a `.py` file named `00xx_xxxxxxxx_public_id.py`, and the `dummy_func` is called later on in the line of `migrations.RunPython(generate_public_ids, dummy_func),`.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
...

# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2020-xx-xx xx:xx

from django.db import migrations, models

...

def generate_public_ids(apps, schema_editor):
    ...

def dummy_func(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
       ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='...',
            name='public_id',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, db_index=True, max_length=32, null=True, verbose_name='short code public identifier'),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(generate_public_ids, dummy_func),
    ]

...
```

Comment: Presumably, to act as a dummy...

Comment: It doesn't have any defined meaning in the language. A function is defined here that happens to be named `dummy_func`, and takes two arguments and doesn't do anything. You probably want to see where it is called.

Comment: As far as Python is concerned it's just a function that happens to be named `dummy_func`. We'd need context to know what its purpose is.

Comment: Absent any evidence of what this is supposed to be used for, I'm going to guess it's garbage code that somebody forgot to clean up before they committed.  I can't think of any useful purpose this might serve.

Comment: If you want to know why someone else's code is written the way it is written, you should ask that person, not Stack Overflow. There is no special meaning to the name `dummy_func`, or really to any name except those starting with an underscore (and even then, it's typically not *that* special). If you really have to understand code from scratch, the way you figure out what a function is for is to look at where it is used.

Comment: Seeing more of the context, I think my "garbage code" assessment is correct.  It's being passed to `RunPython` as the optional `reverse_code` parameter, but it doesn't actually do any reversing.  The parameter should just be omitted and `dummy_func` should be deleted.

Comment: I agree with @Samwise . Updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new context after your edit, it seems like the author of the code referenced the function from someone else (OP) and copy-pasted OP's function. The author didn't want to make use of the 2nd parameter that OP created but was too lazy to change OP's code so he did the lazy method of providing a dummy parameter.

I personally have done what the author did several times. Because, time is of the essence sometimes. Deleting a parameter requires several lines of refactoring whereas creating a dummy function just needs 2 additional lines of code.

---

As the name suggests pass statement simply does nothing. The pass statement in Python is used when a statement is required syntactically but you do not want any command or code to execute. It is like null operation, as nothing will happen is it is executed. Pass statement can also be used for writing empty loops. Pass is also used for empty control statement, function and classes.

Example:

```
def fun():
    pass
```

Comment: In this case, the parameter is optional, so it's literally less work to just delete the unneeded parameter.  It wasn't a matter of saving time, it was just the author not doing a five second Google search to understand how the API worked, possibly combined with not knowing Python very well (if you really *needed* a dummy, it'd be faster to just use a lambda).